# How to load a rdb file inside docker container without using a volume?

Tags: bash, docker, redis, amazon-elasticache

I have a very simple use case on my end

- Download an RDB dump file from S3
- Load it up inside the docker redis container
- Get a list of keys retrieved and email it
- Do the cleanup (delete the downloaded rdb and any other log files generated)
- I am getting an error in the cleanup part where I try to delete the rdb file
- I believe this is because initially the the rdb file as ec2-user:ec2-user set as user and group
- As soon as I mount it as volume inside a docker container, the user changes to something else
- As part of cleanup I want to delete the docker container, the rdb file and any other intermediate log file but I keep getting an operation not permitted error

How can I load an rdb file inside docker redis container without using a volume so that I can delete this file later with a simple rm command?

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e
set -E
set -o pipefail
set -u
set -x

IFS=$'\n\t'

log="/tmp/restore-elasticache-to-docker.log"
exec 2>"$log"

handle_error() {    
    log_message="$(< "$log")"
    local from;
    local to;
    local subject;
    local text;
    from="cron@ch.com"
    to="ch@gmail.com"
    subject="Elasticache restore encountered an error at $(date)"
    text="Elasticache restore encountered an error at line:$(caller) while running:${BASH_COMMAND} due to the error:${log_message}"
    aws ses send-email --from "${from}" --subject "${subject}" --text "${text}" --to "${to}"
    echo "subject: ${subject}"
    echo "text: ${text}"
    exit 1
}

handle_exit() {
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        log_message="$(< "$log")"
        local from;
        local to;
        local subject;
        local text;
        from="cron@ch.com"
        to="ch@gmail.com"
        subject="Elasticache restore completed successfully at $(date)"
        text="Elasticache restore completed successfully ${log_message} ${result}"
        aws ses send-email --from "${from}" --subject "${subject}" --text "${text}" --to "${to}"
        echo "subject: ${subject}"
        echo "text: ${text}"
    fi
    docker stop "${container_name}" && docker rm "${container_name}"
    # THIS LINE GIVES ME AN ERROR SAYING rm: cannot remove '/tmp/test-ch-cluster-001-2023-08-23-10-09-24-0001.rdb': Operation not permitted
    rm "${dump_file_directory}/${dump_file_name}"
    rm /tmp/restore-elasticache-to-docker.log
}

trap 'handle_exit $?' EXIT
trap 'handle_error $?' ERR

bucket='something-something'
container_name="my_redis_container"
dump_file_directory="/tmp"
host="localhost"
port="6379"
result=""

dump_file_name=$(aws s3 ls $bucket --recursive | sort | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $4}')
aws s3 cp "s3://${bucket}/${dump_file_name}"  "/tmp/${dump_file_name}"
docker ps -aq --filter "name=${container_name}" | grep -q . && docker stop "${container_name}" && docker rm -fv "${container_name}"
# I THINK THIS VOLUME HERE IS THE PROBLEM
docker run --detach --name "${container_name}" --publish "${port}:${port}" --volume "/tmp/${dump_file_name}:/data/dump.rdb" redis
until docker exec -it "${container_name}" redis-cli -h "${host}" -p "${port}" ping; do
    sleep 1
done
result=$(docker exec "${container_name}" redis-cli -h "${host}" -p "${port}" keys '*')
```

Comment: AWS has SDKs in many languages, and you should be able to retrieve a file from S3 to an in-memory object.  I'd look into combining this with an ordinary Redis client library, and avoid doing anything Docker-specific here (_e.g._, you don't need `docker exec` to "go inside" the Redis container; just connect to its port 6379).

Comment: @DavidMaze if you see the last line, i am executing a keys * query to get of keys retrieved from the container and email them to the admin